# block['content'] contail both string and form

Tags: 7, blocks

I created a form and used a block to show it. I would like to add a message before the form. Before I added "You can use the form below," the form was working fine. Right now, it doesn't work.

The code is the following one.

```
$block['content'] = '<strong>You can use the form below</strong>';
$block['content'] .= '<strong>Enter your email</strong>';
$block['content'] .= drupal_get_form('custom_request_price_form');
```

It just shows "Array" where it should show a form. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`drupal_get_form` returns an array, so you can't concatenate it with a string.

Something like this will work, using a render array:

```
$block['content'] = [
  'preamble' => [
    '#markup' => '<strong>...</strong>',
  ],
  'form' => drupal_get_form('custom_request_price_form'),
];
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It works. I have a question that how can I find these attitudes name such as "preamble"?

Comment: The identifiers for render arrays (in the above `form` and `preamble`) can be anything you like, as long as they don't begin with a `#`. Drupal treats those beginning with `#` as metadata. `preamble` could be `intro`, for example, and `form` could be `the_form` or `my_form` or whatever, even an integer, so long as it's a valid array key that doesn't start with `#`

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you very much!!!